# Is the total impact of an user's combined accounts visible somewhere or can it be queried in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, people-reached

Is the total impact of an user's combined SE accounts visible somewhere or can it be queried in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?